# How to Pass data from TextView to CardView in Recyclerview which already have data from FireStore

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Studio and I am facing a challenge.

I have FireStore database and I retrieve the data to Textview inside CardView in the Recyclerview and "it works well" in Result_Activity.

In the same Result_Activity, I have Textview that gets x-Number from other activity "Put & Get extras", "and it works well also".

My problem is, I want to pass this x-Number from Textview to Textview inside the Cardview to be shown in the Recyclerview.

And the final result is Cardview with "Data from FireStore in 3 TextView & x-Number in 1 TextView".

I tried to search many examples but nothing work. Is there any way to do this and also I hope there is an example for me to understand how it can be done.

The FirestoreRecyclerAdapter

public class BIRAdaptor extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter {

```
public BIRAdaptor(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<BIR> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BIRAdaptor.BRHolder holder, int position, @NonNull BIR model) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.textViewEmail.setText(model.getEmail());
    holder.textViewInD.setText(model.getInD());
    holder.textViewYs.setText(String.valueOf(model.getYs())); }

@NonNull
@Override
public BIRAdaptor.BRHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rslt_item, parent, false);
    return new BIRAdaptor.BRHolder(v);   }

public void deleteB(int position){
    getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();    }

class BRHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textViewEmail;
    TextView textViewInD;
    TextView textViewYs;

    TextView ttlIns;

    public BRHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName =itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        textViewEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_email);
        textViewInD = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_inD);
        textViewYs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_ys);

        //x-Number
        ttlIns = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_ins);
    }}}
```

How to pass the x-Number from textview to Adapter?

Comment: Could you please explain this line -> I want to bass this x-Number from Textview to Textview?

Comment: x-Number is in Textview other than the Cardview in Recyclerview, and I need to put this x-Number inside the Cardview.

Comment: is The x-Number is same for all cards ? or different for each cards ?

Comment: There are different Data came from FireStore and x-Number will be same in all Cards.

Comment: then just pass the x-Number data to the adapter class as a parameter and use it to place that in view

Comment: How to pass it? as I have Recycler Adaptor and in "onBindViewHolder" I need to pass this Number.

Comment: Post Your Recycler Adapter code in the question

Comment: The x-Number can be identified in it, but I don't know how to get the number from it and set to the Adapter.